# cmake calling python script and verify

Tags: python, c, cmake

I have a python script for doing sanity check on source files. I need to run this python script before compiling source files. How do I write in `CMakeLists.txt` file to ensure the python script get triggered before compilation c code? And how to verify the py get executed? Thanks!

```
project/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── sanitycheck.py
└── *.c source files
```

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `add_custom_target`, and `add_dependencies` to make your normal target depend on it:

```
get_target_property(sources_to_check yourProject SOURCES)
add_custom_target(
    sanity_check
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sanitycheck.py ${sources_to_check}
)
add_dependencies(yourTarget sanity_check)
```

This should ensure that the command is run before compiling the sources of `yourTarget`.

Comment: a better way is to get sources from the target (check `SOURCES` target property and `TARGET_PROPRTY` generator expression) and not to use `file(GLOB)` ... ever %)